# Open an asp.net Page inside of an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, iframe

In my web site I have two pages... one is the `Assistance.aspx`, and the other is `Help01.aspx`
What I want to do is to open the second page inside the `iFrame` which is in a table column this column belongs to a table which is inside of the `Assistance.aspx` page:
For this purpose I use the following code:

```
<iframe id="iFrame" runat="server"  class="tablecolumndiv" >
```

And in my code behind I use:

```
Protected WithEvents iFrame As System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl<br/>
Public frame1 As HtmlControl = CType(Me.FindControl("iFrame"), HtmlControl)
```

But when I come to the:

```
Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
        frame1.Attributes("src") = "/Pages/Support/Asp/Help01.aspx"
End Sub
```

It throws me an error of : 
**`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`**
Because the `Me.FindControl("iFrame")` has value of nothing
That error eliminated when I delete the `runat` from the element.
Why?

*** ADDITIONAL INFORMATION ***

I also use the following script for the same reason:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setPage(frame, pName) {
        document.getElementById(frame).src = pName;
    }
</script>
```

Which I call it from my code behind:

```
Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
        Dim myNewAsp As New AspNetSqlProvider
        myNewAsp.InitializeSite(sender, e)
        Dim url As String = "/Pages/Support/Asp/Help01.aspx"
        Dim urlURI As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
        Dim urlPath As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath
        Dim myServerName As String = Strings.Left(urlURI, urlURI.Length - urlPath.Length)
        root_url = myServerName
        Dim assist As New Assistance
        Dim frameName As String = "iFrame" 'assistiFrame.ID
        iPageLoad(frameName, sender, root_url + url)
End Sub
Public Sub iPageLoad(FrameId As String, sender As Object, msg As String)
        Dim cstype As Type = Me.GetType()
        Dim innerMess As String = msg
        Dim url As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
        Dim script As String = "setPage('" + FrameId + "', '" + innerMess + "')"
        If Not Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered(Me.GetType(), "iPage") Then
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, "iPage", script, True)
        End If
End Sub
```

That script also throws me the same error.

Comment: When you delete the runat=server tag I assume the code itself does not work? Also do you close the iframe tag?

Comment: No the code runs smoothly and I'm not closing the `iFrame`

Comment: Did you tried `iFrame.Attributes("src") = "/Pages/Support/Asp/Help01.aspx"`? Directly, without using FindControl

Comment: This could be due to asp.net 'changing' the id (it does that, appends parent id and all sorts of crap). Run the page and in your browser use chrome dev tools/firebug to inspect the element and check the id (or just viewsource). HOWEVER, for server side controls you do not need to use FindControl, can just reference via id: `iFrame.Attributes`

Comment: Yes I did and runs very good... But when I see on the screen it turns white for two or thee seconds and then gives me the result I need.

Comment: Can't help feeling closing the iframe would help

Comment: Why close the `iFrame` in this area I have to see and use the `Help01.aspx` Page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally we’ve seen that this issue have two solutions, every one of those two solutions have it’s own results.
The first solution is to declare the iFrame like this:

```
Protected WithEvents iFrame As System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl
```

And in the Button_Click handler we use the:

```
iFrame.Attributes("src") = "/Pages/Support/Asp/Help01.aspx"
```

And in the design view area we use the:

```
<iframe id="iFrame" runat="server" class="tablecolumndiv" >
```

This solution works fine, and produces an excellent result.
Of course we have another solution described in the **ADDITIONAL INFORMATION** but that one needs to delete the `runat=”server”` from the declaration in the design view area.
Choose and Pick….